# How Can I Have Multiple Scoped Background Services in Blazor Server Without Code Repetition?

Tags: c#, service, blazor, blazor-server-side

We are writing our first significant Blazor Server application. This application contains two services that we have written. These services essentially run as cron jobs. One of them sends out emails shortly after midnight based on activity from the day before, while the other reviews an Excel spreadsheet that is created daily and then updates some databases based on what it finds.

We would like the services to share a `ScopedBackgroundService.cs`, as its functionality is basic and (in theory) would work fine for either service. Here is that file (based primarily upon code provided by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

```
public sealed class ScopedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> _logger;

    public ScopedBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is running.");

        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is working.");

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IScopedProcessingService scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }


    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is stopping.");
        
        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Here is `IScopedProcessingService.cs`:

```
public interface IScopedProcessingService
{
    Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}
```

Finally, this is from our `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

...

builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PhaseChangeReportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();

...
```

However, if I run the code as written above, the first listed service will fail to run, while the second listed service will run. I can change which service will run and which will fail by swapping the order in which the services are listed.

I copied the `ScopedBackgroundService.cs` file into a second file (named `ScopedBackgroundServiceB.cs`), and did the same to `IScopedProcessingService.cs` (into `IScopedProcessingServiceB.cs`). I then changed `Program.cs` to:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundServiceB>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PhaseChangeReportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingServiceB, PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();
```

And then both services will run!

However, this results in duplicated code re `ScopedBackgroundService.cs` and `IScopedProcessingService.cs`. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Is it possible to avoid this repeated code, or is it necessary?

**Edit With Minimal Repro**

Here is how to achieve a minimal repro of this issue.

- Create a Blazor Server App template in Visual Studio for .NET 7.
- Modify `Program.cs` to the following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundServiceB>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PhaseChangeReportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingServiceB, PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

- Create `IScopedProcessingService.cs`:

```
public interface IScopedProcessingService
{
    Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}
```

- Create `IScopedProcessServiceB.cs`:

```
public interface IScopedProcessingServiceB
{
    Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}
```

- Create `ScopedBackgroundService.cs`:

```
public sealed class ScopedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> _logger;

    public ScopedBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} has been constructed.");
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is running.");

        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is working.");

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IScopedProcessingService scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
       _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is stopping.");

       await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

- Create `ScopedBackgroundServiceB.cs`:

```
public sealed class ScopedBackgroundServiceB : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundServiceB> _logger;

    public ScopedBackgroundServiceB(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<ScopedBackgroundServiceB> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundServiceB)} has been constructed.");
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundServiceB)} is running.");

        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundServiceB)} is working.");

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IScopedProcessingServiceB scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingServiceB>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundServiceB)} is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

- Create `PhaseChangeReportService.cs`:

```
public sealed class PhaseChangeReportService : IScopedProcessingService
{
    private readonly ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> _logger;

    public PhaseChangeReportService(ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PhaseChangeReportService)} is constructed.");
    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PhaseChangeReportService)} is working.");

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 * 10, stoppingToken);

            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PhaseChangeReportService)} has produced a 10-second unit of work.");
        }
    }
}
```

- Create `PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService.cs`:

```
public class PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService : IScopedProcessingServiceB
{
    private readonly ILogger<PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService> _logger;

    public PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService(ILogger<PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService)} is constructed.");
    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService)} is working.");

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 * 10, stoppingToken);

            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService)} has produced a 10-second unit of work.");
        }
    }
}
```

At this point you can run the solution and the console will output the logs of the creation and execution of the various services. Notably, **both** PhaseChangeReportService and PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService will execute on their 10-second timers.

However, if you...

- comment out `builder.Services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundServiceB>();` from `Program.cs`,
- change `builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingServiceB, PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();` to `builder.Services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();` in `Program.cs`, and
- update `PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService.cs` to implement ScopedBackgroundService (instead of ScopedBackgroundServiceB),

then only PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService will execute. Nothing
will be logged regarding PhaseChangeReportService in this
circumstance.

Currently the only fix I know for this is the original setup, which involves repeating the code within `IScopedProcessingService.cs` and `ScopedBackgroundService.cs`. As this violates a fundamental principle of coding (Don't Repeat Yourself), I want to see if there is another way.

Comment: Please post a minimal repro.

Comment: `public interface IPhaseChangeReportService : IScopedProcessingService  { }`

Comment: [Polite] Why do you want to build what are essentially scheduled tasks with no UI into Blazor?  While it's possible, is it the best solution?

Comment: @StephenCleary I will look into doing so.

Comment: @BrianParker Converting the service classes to interfaces gets me a System.ArgumentException when builder.Build() is called in Program.cs. Apparently I cannot instantiate the same implementation type as the service type. Is there another step that I'm missing?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis We have had issues in the past with Windows Server Scheduled Tasks and don't trust them if we can avoid it. We also like having a single codebase for this entire application, as we use EF Core and the 'scheduled tasks' work with those entities.

Comment: @StephenCleary I've added a minimal repro.

Comment: @NeilWehneman I believe Brian was advising to create and use an interface inheriting from `IScopedProcessingService` for each of your services and use them instead of `IScopedProcessingService` in Program.cs

Comment: @NeilWehneman - What makes you think you can trust a web service to do the job any better?  If your scheduled Tasks didn't work correctly, then you're probably doing some exotic things that are likely to cause problems wherever you do them.  Whenever I hear "import from `Excel`" I go into hiding!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<PhaseChangeReportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<PlannerOrderStatusUpdateService>();
```

and use:

```
public SomeClassContstructor(PhaseChangeReportService phaseChangeReport...) { ... }
```

You don't have to register a service with an interface, but will mean your implementation would be through the class and not the interface, which could impact reusability and maintainability when migrating to different technologies.

Unless you do something like this:

```
using IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

var implementationTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x =>
            !x.IsInterface //Optional if you might use the interface on other interfaces
            && x.GetInterface(typeof(IScopedProcessingService).Name) != null
        );

foreach (var implementationType in implementationTypes)
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(implementationType);

    await (service as IScopedProcessingService).DoWorkAsync(...);
}
```

You can use a similar snippet like the above to add your services in your `Program.cs`